# Relative path to external dependencies in Slim PHP using $app->render()

Tags: php, html, rest, slim

If I render an actual html site with external dependencies (javascript/css) using

```
$app->render("./somewhere/index.html");
```

or

```
echo "<html>...</html>";
```

for some reason slim cant resolve the dependency paths - so the site can't be loaded correctly. An workaround is $app->redirect("./somewhere/index.html"); instead of $app->render("./somewhere/index.html"); - but then also the URL path in browsers adress bar changes. I want to avoid that, because I just want to display an HTML template for the REST request I'm receiving from the URI - so theres no point to redirect to an html document and lose the REST Parameters.

An sscce for my problem:

dir structure:

```
- index.php
+ templates
|-- index.html
|-- dependency.js
+ Slim
|-- ...
|-- ...
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $app->render('index.html');
});
$app->run();
?>
```

/templates/index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SSCCE</title>
    <script id="someid" type="text/javascript" src="dependency.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:func_test()">Click here</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

/templates/dependency.js:

```
function func_test() {
  alert("Test");
}
```

1.) Success: 
Access the /templates/index.html directly. (i.e. by entering 127.0.0.1/templates/index.html). Clicking on 'Click here' opens a message box.

2.) Failure: 
Access the index.php File from Slim (note: I haven't activated mod_rewrite on the webserver - so I'm using index.php/.../ as URI i.e. 127.0.0.1/index.php/testid). The html site loads correctly, but if I click on 'Click here' nothing happens.

I already tried: different variants of src="../dependency.js", src="../templates/dependency.js", changing index.html into an php file and using src="$webroot/templates/dependency.js" - but nothing worked. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think youre confusing how you would typically work with Slim (or another similat Microframework like Silex). Your assets like JS/CSS/images shouldnt be realtive to your routed url because that routed url doesnt map directly to a file system based resource. The should be absolute. Your setup should look something like this:

```
Slim/
templates/
  index.html
  whatever.html
images/
js/
  /dependency.js
css/
```

So all your js references should look something like:

`src="/js/dependency.js"`

Unless you want to write some kind of special controller to serve up the correct resources based on a template or somethings. But if your application layout is complex enough that something liek this is required, you should probably be using something more like Symfony2 or ZF that has a concept of modules/bundles that encapsulate complete sets of functionality.

Additionally, you shouldnt be able to access templates publicly by URL because those should only be served by your Slim controllers. In fact i normally wouldnt have the templates inside the document root. My normal setup usually looks something like this (`public` would be the webserver document root):

```
Slim/
templates/
  index.html
public/
  index.php
  js/
  images/
  css/
```